# React Router DOM Load component only if needed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have this fully functional and very basic code:

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch} from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./App/home.jsx";
import About from "./App/about.jsx";

ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home}></Route>
            <Route path="/About" component={About}></Route>
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>,
    document.getElementById("main")
);
```

I realise that no matter what, `Home` and `About` components is always going to be loaded, but not always used.

How can I fix this? I've tried:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch} from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./App/home.jsx";
import About from "./App/about.jsx";
let path = require("path");

function C(file) {
    return function(obj) {
        let url = path.join("./App", file);
        let C = require(url);
        return <C {...obj}/>
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={C("home.jsx")}></Route>
            <Route exact path="/" component={C("about.jsx")}></Route>
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>,
    document.getElementById("main")
);
```

But then, it doesn't get rendered.

So is there any way that I can load only the components I need for the current web page.

Comment: I havent used code splitting but Is this achievable with code splitting? https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html

Comment: @MaxCarrol What do you mean bu code splitting?

Comment: It where the components are lazily loaded and loaded only if that have to be, Like this you can prevent all your imports being loaded regardless of whether they are needed or not

Comment: Thanks for the link @MaxCarrol, While, it's a nice idea, it's not what I was looking for. I was saying, that I am importing `Home` and `About`, but one of them will not even be used. So, can I make sure, that I only load the one I need.

Comment: @LearnforFun just read the documentation from the link that MaxCarrol sent you

Comment: Thanks @MaxCarroll, after a thorough search in the documentation and a few times trying, Suspense and Lazy did it. If it were an answer, I would have accepted it.

Comment: Oh right, I originally questioned the legitimacy of my answer and thought it wouldnt work, I have undeleted my answer now 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

perhaps using code splitting in this fashion

https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html

```
import React, { Suspense } from 'react';

const OtherComponent = React.lazy(() => import('./OtherComponent'));
const AnotherComponent = React.lazy(() => import('./AnotherComponent'));

function MyComponent() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
        <section>
          <OtherComponent />
          <AnotherComponent />
        </section>
      </Suspense>
    </div>
  );
}
```

So perhaps your code could be like this

```
I have this fully functional and very basic code:

import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch} from "react-router-dom";


const Home= React.lazy(() => import('./App/home.jsx'));
const About= React.lazy(() => import('./App/about.jsx'));

ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home}></Route>
            <Route path="/About" component={About}></Route>
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>,
    document.getElementById("main")
);
```

Comment: @LearnforFun I have undeleted my answer

Comment: BTW, for the 2nd example, passing in a `React.lazy` as a component didn't work, but putting the `Switch` into a `Suspense` did work. :)

Comment: I think to truley do what you want those lazy loaders need to moved inside some conditional logic which checks the route, I was thinking about using the hooks provided by react router dom `useRouteMatch``to check the route before rendering the component. You could write a new component to handle this which uses `useRouteMatch` and lazy loading and returns a component or null  if the route doesn't match maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `React-Loadable` package for the use-case you mentioned above. Example code is shown below, follow along with it.

```
import Loadable from 'react-loadable';

const loading = () => (
   <div>
       Loading... //Custom loader
   </div>
);

const AsyncLogin = Loadable({
   loader: () => import('./Login/index.jsx'),
   loading: loading,
});

ReactDOM.render(
<BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
        <Route path='/login' component={AsyncLogin} />
    </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>,
document.getElementById("main"));
```

You can find the `react-loadable` documentation [here](https://github.com/jamiebuilds/react-loadable#readme). Or alternatively, you can configure [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/) and achieve the required results.